# Change the links in Ask Ubuntu Meta contact page

Tags: bug, status-completed, https

I recently noticed the [Ask Ubuntu Meta contact page](https://meta.askubuntu.com/contact).

[image: Screenshot of Ask Ubuntu Meta contact page]

- The [Yahoo link](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/helpcentral) redirects to https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
- The [Google link](http://www.google.com/contact/) is HTTP and redirects to https://about.google/contact-google/.
- The [Ubuntu link](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us) is HTTP and redirects to https://ubuntu.com/contact-us.

Please fix these issues.

Comment: What is the issue? Where should the links point to instead?

Comment: @terdon OP means the last 2 links are http instead of https in the contact page. The first one links to `https://help.yahoo.com/kb/helpcentral` which ends up redirecting to `https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account`. OP is asking to update all links so they directly go to the correct place instead of relying on redirects.

Comment: Oh. I see, since the URLs shown were `https` that wasn't clear. Thanks, @Dan. I don't honestly see why this is a problem worth spending precious developer time on, but at least I can understand what is being requested now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UI I normally use for updating the text on this page is only available on main sites - it's a special CM-only hub with stats and special links that we need that allow us to do a variety of things.

Since this doesn't exist for metas, I was a bit at a loss of how to make this change... until I realized the site setting that the UI edits is also accessible to me directly and I can access the meta site settings in addition to the main site ones. As such, I've updated the text on meta - which had never been done as far as I can tell. So... yay?

Comment: Please look into this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372042

Comment: You know... it's really, really frustrating to have someone just constantly asking for more and more and more and never even bothering to say "thanks".

Comment: I am sorry Catija. I am not forcing you to do it. Please take your time. Thanks a lot for fixing a lot stuff. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: *which had never been done before* hahaha amazing! One small step for Catija, one giant leap for SEkind. I didn't even know this contact page was there. Thanks so much!